# How to make submenus drop down below parent menu, instead of flying out?

Tags: html, css

I made a jsFiddle of a menu that flies out:

http://jsfiddle.net/ZSMLg/1/

Here is the code, which I got from the following post:

[Simple CSS fly out list, not so simple?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3790677/simple-css-fly-out-list-not-so-simple)

```
<ul>
    <li>home</li>
    <li>products
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">CPUs</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">AMD<a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">AM2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">AM3</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Intel</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Motherboards</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">PSUs</a></li>
            <li>Hard drives
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">HDD</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">SSD</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Tracking</li>
</ul>
```

The CSS is as below:

```
ul {list-style-type: none; width: 8em; border: 1px solid #000; padding: 0;}
/* just to set the base-line for the ul, but note the width. It's important. */

ul li {position: relative; border-top: 1px solid #000; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
/* the position: relative is used to allow its child elements to be absolutely positioned */

ul li:first-child {border-top: 0 none transparent; }
/* to avoid a two-pixel border on the first li (1px li-border + 1px ul-border) */

ul li:hover {background-color: #f90; }
/* just to aid visually */

ul ul {position: absolute; top: -1px; left: 8em; display: none; }
/* sets up all ul elements beneath the parent ul, the -px is to counter the movement forced by the border, bear in mind that the li:first-child doesn't *have* a border, so adjust to taste */

ul > li:hover > ul {display: block; }
/* makes the nested list appear if the parent-li is hovered */
```

How should the CSS look like, if i want the submenus to come beneath the parent menu, slightly pushed to the left?

Comment: You must reduce the `left: 8em;` of `ul ul` to 7 or 7.5em.. But if you do this the href texts will get overlapped...

Comment: I would like the menu to drop down vertically, and expand the whole menu tree, not overlap, if this is possible with CSS only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try delete `position: absolute;`, replace in the css this code:

```
ul ul {position: absolute; top: -1px; left: 8em; display: none; }

ul > li:hover > ul {display: block; }
```

With this one:

```
ul ul { display: none; }

ul > li:hover > ul { margin-left:20%; display: block; }
```